# Manually calling a wicket event handler for a component

Tags: java, event-handling, wicket

I'm working on a Wicket application and I've defined an `onchange` event handler for a `DropDownChoice` and I'd like to manually call the handler. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Code example:

```
DropDownChoice<String> choices = new DropDownChoice<String>(
  "choices",
  new Model<String>(),
  Arrays.asList("First", "Second", "Third");

choices.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

I know that I could do pull the contents of `onUpdate` out into it's own method and just call that method but I'm curious to know whether there is a way the event handler directly.

I know `WicketTester` can simulate a component being clicked or changed. Perhaps the way it does it would work?

Cheers,

Caps

Comment: What is the use case ? AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior should be used to update the component's model and make some Ajax updates. You can update the model with dropDown.setModelObject("Second") but I don't see no reason to try to use AjaxRequestTarget in non-Ajax request.

Comment: Basically there's just a few different calls to update other components that will have data changed based on what has changed in this component. I'd like to preselect the first option from the DropDownChoice when I create the layout and then have each component that is dependent on it update as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wicket 1.5 there is an eventbus for such use cases. In prior versions, you'll have to emulate this. There are other questions related to this. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318091/wicket-and-complex-ajax-scenarios))

Answer (score 0):

To call it from JavaScript or Jquery, you can call

```
htmlElement.trigger("change");
```

It is calling AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") in Wicket 1.6.