# A matter of style - member variables vs. get(path)

Tags: coding-style, wicket

Whenever I have to add some component (A) to the AjaxRequestTarget of another component (B) (usualy both children of the same parent, I face the same decision:

Make A a member-variable of the parent component vs. using the parents get(path) method. Both variants seem to have pros and cons and I can't really decide which would be better from the perspective of "better" code...

The first variant is stable even if the path of (A) changes but leaves the parent cluttered with members that are only rarely used. The other variant results in a cleaner parent class but adds multiple points of failure when the component hierarchy changes. Additional this variant either litters the class with magic strings (the paths) or string constants (when I put the paths there)...

Any hints would be apreciated.

Edit: This applies to Wicket 1.4 since Wicket 1.5 solves this with its EventBus

Comment: I can send you the solution I came up with to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318091/wicket-and-complex-ajax-scenarios It wraps the `Model` of a trigger component and when `setObject()` is called, all the listeners who subscribed to that change will be added to the request target. It's not great but it does away with the need to reference updated components explicitly.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks but I decided to push the migration to 1.5 over the weekend. It was planned for the near future anyway anyway...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Wicket 1.5's event mechanism instead to update components using Ajax. This way you will decouple publisher and subscriber. See for example my presentation on new [features in Wicket 1.5 given at JavaZone'11](http://vimeo.com/28791557) (skip to about 51 minutes into the talk).

Taken from the Wicket 1.5 release notes:

### Inter-component events

Wicket 1.5 offers a simple, yet flexible, way for component to communicate with each other in a decoupled manner. The two major interfaces that facilitate this are:

```
/**
 * Objects that can send events
 */
public interface IEventSource {
    <T> void send(IEventSink sink, Broadcast broadcast, T payload);
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Objects that can receive events
 */
public interface IEventSink
{
    /**
     * Called when an event is sent to this sink
     */
    void onEvent(IEvent<?> event);
}
```

The classes that implement these interfaces, and can thus participate in the event mechanism are: `Component`, `RequestCycle`, `Session`, and `Application`.

The mechanism allows for different event broadcast methods defined here:

```
/**
 * Defines the event broadcast type.
 */
public enum Broadcast {
    BREADTH,
    DEPTH,
    BUBBLE,
    EXACT;
}
```

There is an [example in wicket-examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/events/) which demonstrates the usage of this.

Applications can register custom event dispatchers in FrameworkSettings; the dispatchers can be used to build custom event delivery mechanisms. For example a custom IEventDispatcher mechanism can route events to annotated methods, for example:

```
public class MyComponent extends Component {
    @OnEvent
    private void onUserAdded(UserAddedEvent event) {...}
}
```

where `UserAddedEvent` is the event payload object.

The default `Component#onEvent` method will be called even if custom dispatchers are registered.

A default event is raised whenever Wicket begins to create an AJAX response. The payload of the event is the AjaxRequestTarget used for event. Sample implementation:

```
// component that always adds itself to the ajax response
public class MyComponent extends Component {
    public void onEvent(IEvent event) {
        if (event.getPayload() instanceof AjaxRequestTarget) {
            ((AjaxRequestTarget)event.getPayload()).add(this);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but right now I'm still on Wicket 1.4.18 and the backport of the Eventbus proved harder that it seemed at first glance. Maybe I should try to get the migration done then...

Comment: I spent the weekend migrating to 1.5, where the problem doesn't occur... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I partially back ported events to Wicket 1.3 for ajax interactions which should work with 1.4.  It doesn't have all the features in Wicket 1.5 events and not nearly as efficient but so far it's worked well. You may find it useful to decouple your components.

As and added bonus, the events work across pages created from (1) modal window page creator (2) popups

It's too much source code to publish here, but here is the link to the sample project + source:

https://github.com/robmcguinness/wicket-events

Examples in source include events that communicate from: (1) page to panel (2) modal page to page opener (3) popup window to page opener