# Wicket - passing control between modal window and form

Tags: wicket

I'd like to have a modal window that gets displayed when the user submits a form. Inside the modal window is a second form that the user has to fill in and submit. If the second form has no errors, then the original form should get submitted, too. If the second form has error, the original form should not get submitted.

Can I achieve this in Wicket in a relatively clean way? Our current solution uses Javascript, but it feels very hacky and the code is very hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event bus in Wicket 1.5 seems to be the right solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6331130/467874